# Search thread using by created and assigned username in Forum section Orchard CMS

Tags: multithreading, search, orchardcms, forum

Please check the attached images. I want to search the thread using by created username and assigned username. But i am getting the result only when I search using by assigned username. When i use the created username i am not getting the result.

Please help to resolve this issue. It is not happen in an Orchardpros.net site.

How can i do Orchardpros.net - 'My Tickets' concept. This is the one for my requirement.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kj4PA.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ILcS.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go to you admin panel then do this:

1. Settings > Search
2. Select the index you're working with
3. Tick the checkbox next to author
4. Click Save

Either wait a few minutes for the index to update itself or then go to:

1. Settings > Indexes
2. Find the index you're working with
3. Press rebuild

After that it should be included in your search results.